# Converting and rounding Large decimal values

Tags: vba, integer, decimal, rounding, long-integer

I have a form where user inputs the Sales Price and vba calculates the commission based on a fixed percentage and then calculates advertisement fees (again a percentage). The advertisement fees is deducted from the commission to arrive at the net commission. I have written the following code:

```
Dim sales, comm, conj As Long

comm = 0

conj = 0

sales = 0

sales = [Forms]![Frmaddnewsales]![txtsales]

comm = sales * .019 

conj = comm * .09 

Exit Sub
```

As an example, I enter sales price as $650000028, it calculates commission=12350000.532 and then conj=1111500.
I need both the comm and conj variable to store only rounded values(without decimals). My question is since my variables are declared as Long why is it storing decimals. Why is comm showing in decimal whereas and conj variable is only showing the rounded figure.

Comment: What programming language? Looks like VBA?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to one of the syntactic quirks of VB. This line:

```
Dim sales, comm, conj As Long
```

Means only `conj` is `Long`. The first two are of type `Variant`. You can try this:

```
Dim sales as Long, comm as Long, conj as Long
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 1 min, it's amazing how often this one comes up.